# I've created a branch on GitHub. Now how do I delete it?

Tags: github

I know this is possible using git commands but I can specifically delete a branch in the user interface (github.com)?

Answer (score 5):

GitHub Help has a great section on [Creating and Deleting Branches](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository) from within the UI.

From within the **Repository** of the project from which you want to delete a branch go to the **Branches** tab. From there you will have the option to delete branches using a button on the right-hand side:
[image: GitHub Deleting Branches]